# Display an image in html from javascript ArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, web, websocket

I'm pretty new to javascript, and only use it to test some server code. I use websockets. From the websocket i get an object blob, which I can convert to an BufferArray. How can I display an image that is stored inside this BufferArray?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Thank you, it does.

Comment: glad to be helpful!